# How i can correct that :"this script is locked to other domain"

Tags: php, pdf, search-engine

I have this website and I got the script(Pdf search engine) which is licensed to all domains ,i installed on http://pdfsearchmachine.com and it is working fine ,but when I installed it on my other domain , http://findfreepdf.com and i did search ,it is saying that this script is locked to another domain ,as I contact the support but they are not responding to my emails ,how I can correct that ,it is written in PHP.please help

Comment: Nothing you can do but wait for their support to contact you back.

Comment: If it's in PHP, you could hack up the code to remove or bypass the domain check, but if this is commercially licensed code, then that's most likely a license violation.

Comment: @Marc B: most of commercial code is obfuscated and protected by tools like IonCube

Comment: It's PHP, however, you can always undo the obfuscation.

Comment: @Marc B: Yes, you can do deobfuscation and lots of things form reverse engineering. But it often protected by cryptographic tools (see IonCube) and so on. Most of time it isn't worth to break into.

Answer (score 0):

Well as temporary workaround, you could [preload another script](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) that sets `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` and `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` or with putenv() maybe. As much as such licensing code uses obfuscation, it usually relies on just environment variables for checking. Note that you might need to reset both variables to correct values for further processing.